# What is the fastest way of Boost::compute vector partial sum

Tags: boost, opencl, boost-compute

I have a vector of 10M float.
I want to know sum of every 100 elements, so 10000 sums in total.
What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: If you can use `OpenCL` 2, then I recommend @huseyin's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861492/what-is-the-optimum-opencl-2-kernel-to-sum-floats)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `reduce_by_key` algorithm, fancy iterators and Boost.Compute lambda expr. Every 100 elements are marked with the same key and reduced. I'm not sure if you can replace `keys_output` with a `discard_iterator` to save some performance.

```
boost::compute::vector<int> keys_output(values_input.size()/100, context);
boost::compute::vector<int> values_output(values_input.size()/100, context);

boost::compute::reduce_by_key(
    boost::compute::make_transform_iterator(
      boost::compute::make_counting_iterator<int>(0),
      boost::compute::_1 / 100
    ),
    boost::compute::make_transform_iterator(
      boost::compute::make_counting_iterator<int>(values_input.size()),
      boost::compute::_1 / 100
    ),
    values_input.begin(),
    keys_output.begin(), 
    values_output.begin(),
    queue
 );
```

Comment: For sure it's not as fast as hand-written OpenCL code. This is a special case. On most GPUs you will be able to sum each 100 elements from vector in one or two steps (kernels).